# how to use pulp to generate variables and constraints of sparse matrix?

Tags: sparse-matrix, pulp

there,
I am new to pulp. I learn pulp from some examples I got online. These examples are very helpful and now I am able to write simple models by mtself. But I still feel difficult to build complex model, especailly model with sparse matrix.

Could you please kindly post with some complex examples with sparse matrix, and conplex constraints. I want to learn how to create necessary variables only, instead of simple one, such as, y = LpVariable.dicts("y", (Factorys, Customers) ,0,1,LpBinary).

I have another question: What happen if I simply use y = LpVariable.dicts("y", (Factorys, Customers) ,0,1,LpBinary) to define variables, in which most of variables are useless in model objective function and constraints, and I add some constraints to explicitly set such useless variable to 0? Does pulp algorithm is able to firstly identify such uesless variables and remove them first, then run Integer Programming algorithm (such as B&B or B&C) to solve the problem with reduced size? If this is true, It looks the "setting useless variable to 0" method will not decrease the solution speed at all. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

This may help

http://www.stuartmitchell.com/journal/2012/2/3/my-top-n-tips-for-python-coding-in-optimisation-1.html

In particular generate a set of of factories and customers first that is sparse.

```
factories_customers = [(f,c) for f in factories for c in customers 
                             if <insert your condition here>]
```

Then use

```
y = LpVariable.dicts("y", factories_customers ,0,1,LpBinary)
```

Pulp does not remove "useless" variables and constraints so the model build time will be long.

However, the solution algorithms (CBC by default contain pre-solve algorithms that will remove the variables).

Comment: Thank you, Stuart. So the solution time will not have much differences if I explicit set useless variables to zero. How much differences of model building time could be. I think model building time usually are seconds or 1 minute around, compared to solution time, model building time are quite small.